# How can I disable numba debug logging when DEBUG env variable is set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I have a lot of numba compiled functions and classes in my code. For the sake of testing I have to run my program like this:

```
DEBUG=True python3 main.py
```

But when I start my program like this, numba prints tons of debug messages to stderr. These messages look like this:

```
2020-02-05 16:28:30,886 - numba.interpreter - DEBUG - label 0:
__numba_self_ = arg(0, name=__numba_self_) ['__numba_self_']
args = arg(1, name=args)                 ['args']
$4load_attr.1 = getattr(value=__numba_self_, attr=find) ['$4load_attr.1', '__numba_self_']
$8call_function_ex.3 = call $4load_attr.1(*args, func=$4load_attr.1, args=[], kws=[], vararg=args) ['$4load_attr.1', '$8call_function_ex.3', 'args']
$10return_value.4 = cast(value=$8call_function_ex.3) ['$10return_value.4', '$8call_function_ex.3']
return $10return_value.4                 ['$10return_value.4']
```

How can I disable this output, without unsetting DEBUG environment variable?

Answer (score 14):

```
import logging

numba_logger = logging.getLogger('numba')
numba_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

will do the job. Just call at the beginning of your script!

Answer (score 4):

Numba is supposed to have environment variables to control this with a config file or [environment variables](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/envvars.html#envvar-NUMBA_DEBUG). But the environment variable that sounds like what we want, `NUMBA_DEBUG`, hasn't worked for me yet. Hopefully, it works for other people?

Comment: It would be nice if you can add the specific environment variables you used instead of only linking to the documentation. The link could be outdated in the future. Also I'm not really sure if this is enough for a good answer. I might be wrong. Nevertheless, it is worth to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), too.

Comment: I agree my answer isn't good since there I no solution and would be better as a comment. I figured something is better than nothing since because it seems like this is supposed to work.


I linked the environment variable that I think should work, `NUMBA_DEBUG`. I'll put that in my answer. Thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it!

Comment: `NUMBA_DEBUG=0` worked for me. I have an application built with PyInstaller and when running from the built packaged binary, NUMBA's debug output is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Related: use this code to idiomatically suppress all numba warnings:

```py
from numba.core.errors import NumbaWarning

import warnings

warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=NumbaWarning)
```

According to the [numba docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/deprecation.html#suppressing-deprecation-warnings), this is the idiomatic way to silence numba warnings. The linked docs have a demonstration for how to use their API to suppress deprecation warnings, but the format works for all warning types listed in [`numba.core.errors`](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/main/numba/core/errors.py).